# Принцип работы библиотеки AndroidTreeView

Tags: java, android

Такой вопрос, необходимо построить дерево. Родитель -дети.
Собираюсь выводить данные из БД (т.е  родителя и  детей)
сама библиотека:
[AndroidTreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView)

как правильно воспользоваться данной либой:
нужно создать фрагмент в котором создать listview ?

это я должен указать в oncreate?

```
TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();
TreeNode parent = new TreeNode(поле из бд(родитель));
 TreeNode child0 = new TreeNode(дети);
 TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode(дите);
 parent.addChildren(child0, child1);
 root.addChild(parent);
```

этот код добавить в фрагмент?

```
 AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(getActivity(), root);
 containerView.addView(tView.getView());
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, всё необходимо добавить в метод `onCreateView`, где Вы создаете UI элементы из XML-файла. Должно получиться что-то подобное:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

        FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.container);
        AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(getActivity(), root);
        containerView.addView(tView.getView());

        return view;
    }
}
```

your_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

В качестве контейнера может выступать любой наследник `ViewGroup`, внутрь которого Вы хотите добавить дерево; это не обязательно `FrameLayout`.

В моём примере не обязательно делать `findViewById`, потому что `view` имеет всего один элемент, но в общем случае это необходимо.

Comment: `containerView` а что под этим подразумевается?

Comment: Любой наследник `ViewGroup` (`FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` и т.д.) расположенный на `view` Вашего фрагмента, внутрь которого Вы хотите добавить UI-элемент, который рисует дерево.